# Web page blank when off local network

Tags: asp.net, iis, routes

I am trying to set up a web site and service using .NET 4, hosted in IIS.  I've added the appropriate ports to be forwarded on my router, as well as enabling port triggering for the appropriate ports, and setting up the box that is hosting IIS to also host DMZ.  I'm not an expert at routing by any means.  The firewall is also allowing access.  The port is 80.

When I attempt to access the web page while on my network, either via internal or public IP, all is well.  When I leave the network, if I attempt to access the page via public IP, all I get is a blank page... no errors or messages.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see anything in the IIS server logs when connecting via the public IP? Usually you can find them at %systemdrive%\inetmgr\Logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1.

Comment: Missed the edit limit of 5 minutes, a bit more below from the previous question.

What happens if you telnet to your public IP on port 80?

It sounds like you have tried to use 3 different methods to open your website for inbound connections, port triggering, port forwarding and dmz. You should only require either DMZ or port forwarding and port forwarding is the better option since it reduces the attack surface area of your server. I suggest removing all except the port forwarding,

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem was related to my ISP not liking people using port 80.  Switched to an obscure port and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try to ask your internet provider wich ports are open for public access. Some time only few port are open